# Apply value replacement using data dictionary

Tags: r, replace

```
df1=c("blue,green,green", "blue", "green")
dictionary=data.frame(label=c("blue","green"),value=c(1,2))
want=c("1,2,2","1","2")
```

I am looking to replace some data using a data dictionary. The data (df1) may have multiple entries in one cell, separated by a comma. I have looked at str_replace_all and I was able to do so by`str_replace_all(colors,c("blue"="1","green"="2"))` but I was unable to create `c("blue"="1","green"="2")` using the dictionary data frame. I have over a hundred items to code so hard coding is not an option.
Any guidance on how to make that work or another way around would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a named vector from dictionary and use `str_replace_all`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tibble)
dictionary %>% 
   mutate(value = as.character(value)) %>%
   deframe %>%
   str_replace_all(df1, .)
#[1] "1,2,2" "1"     "2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a base R option:

```
rename <- with(dictionary, setNames(value, label))

lapply(strsplit(df1, ","), \(x) unname(rename[x])) |>
  lapply(\(x) paste(x, collapse = ",")) |> 
  unlist()

[1] "1,2,2" "1"     "2"
```

Comment: This looks really neat! But somehow I got this. Did I do something wrong when pasting?
> lapply(strsplit(df1, ","), \(x) unname(rename[x])) |>
Error: unexpected input in "lapply(strsplit(df1, ","), \"
>   lapply(\(x) paste(x, collapse = ",")) |> 
Error: unexpected input in "  lapply(\"
>   unlist()
Error in unlist() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

Comment: @TerryCai make sure your R version is at least 4.1.0. The native pipe operator `|>` and the shorthand function `\(x)` started in this version.

Comment: Ah I see. I have 3.6 right now and was quite unfamiliar with `|>`.  Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 2):

Base R Option 1 using nested `vapply()` 's:

```
# dict => named integer vector
dict <- setNames(dictionary$value, dictionary$label)

# Loop through and replace values: df1_replaced => character vector
df1_replaced <- vapply(
   df1, 
   function(x){
      y <- strsplit(
         x, 
         ","
      )
      vapply(
         y, 
         function(z){
            toString(
               dict[
                  match(
                     z, 
                     names(dict)
                     )
                  ]
            )
         },
         character(1)
      )
   },
   character(1),
   USE.NAMES = FALSE
)
```

Comment: I think you missed `dict=with(dictionary, setNames(value, label))`. But thank you so much!

Comment: @TerryCai Sorry I did miss posting it please see my amended solution above !  Good pickup !